# Python getting files from sourceforge

Tags: python, sourceforge

Hello I am making a program, and I need it to download an exe from sourceforge. I have the download link which leads it to the "wait 5 seconds thing". How can I download the file from it, and save it to the cwd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML file you get contains a refresh link:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/...">
```

You can search the HTML document for that element, extract the url, then download that.

However, remember to respect the [robots.txt](http://sourceforge.net/robots.txt) file. I.e. have a delay of at least one second between requests and do not try to download disallowed paths.

Edit: Actually, the downloads subdomain has [its own](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/robots.txt) robots.txt that prohibits all automated downloads, so you should not do this. You could e.g. open a link in the user's web browser instead.

Comment: got it using urllib.urlretrieve

Comment: They literally have documentation on scraping their downloads https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Downloading%20files%20via%20the%20command%20line/